# Character Position Range in vb.NET

Tags: vb.net

I need to get the range of the starting and ending character positions of a string of text, which is supposed to be the question or answer in a game of Jeopardy. I've determined the beginning and ending positions, but I don't know how to tell VB.NET what the range is.

I've tried using the `CharacterRange` code, but it says it's a *structure type* and *cannot be used as an expression*.

```
Public MsgStartEndRange As CharacterRange

Dim MsgStartCharPos, MsgEndCharPos, MsgLength As Integer

MsgStartCharPos = input.IndexOf("<" & tag & ">") + 2 + Len(tag)
MsgEndCharPos = input.IndexOf("</" & tag & ">") - 1
MsgStartEndRange = CharacterRange(input.IndexOf(MsgEndCharPos), input.IndexOf(MsgStartCharPos))
```

Please help me where you can. This is my first time asking for help with this site.

Comment: You do not need to use `CharacterRange` to operate on strings. You need to use [`Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Something makes me think that you are trying to parse html text. If it is so, then don't do it yourself. There are free libraries that do that job very well.

Comment: What do *you* mean by "range"? Do you want a combination of start-index and end-index (two numbers), or the text between those indices (aka a substring)?

Comment: MsgStartEndRange = New CharacterRange(...)